# VBA Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I receive Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch when I try to run the code.  Debug highlights the 'IF' and 'ElseIF' statements, but I can't figure out where the mistake is.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim rgMonth As Range
Dim rgTaxExp As Range

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set rgTaxExp = Range(Cells(lRow, 10), Cells(lRow, lColumn))

Set rgMonth = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(2, lColumn))
For i = 1 To rgMonth.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To rgMonth.Columns.Count

If Month(date2) >= Month(rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value) Then 'Runtime Error '13':_
Type Mismatch
Cells(lRow, 9).Copy rgTaxExp.Cells(i, j)
ElseIf Month(date2) < Month(rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value) Then 'Runtime Error '13':_
Type Mismatch
rgTaxExp.Cells(i, j) = 0
```

Comment: Where / how is `date2` declared / defined ?

Comment: It's declared several lines above                                                           Dim date1 As Date
date1 = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
Dim date2 As Date
date2 = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value

'DateDiff = ("m", date1, date2)

Comment: What is the value of rgMonth.Cells(i, j) when the code fails ?

Comment: The code never runs through to yield a value.

Comment: When you set the value of `lColumn` you qualify the reference with `ws` - i.e. `ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. None of the other references - e.g. for `rgMonth`, `rgTaxExp` - are qualified with `ws` and thus will refer to the active worksheet (which might not be the same one as `ws`)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, either `Month(date2)` or `Month(rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value)` is failing at some point in your loop.

Insert two debug statements before the If statement that is causing the error:

```
For j = 1 To rgMonth.Columns.Count

Debug.Print "date2 is " & date2
Debug.Print "rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value is " & rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value

If Month(date2) >= Month(rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value) Then 'Runtime Error '13':_
Type Mismatch
```

Run your code. When you get to the error, debug and take a look at the Immediate window. The last 2 lines should show you why the error is occurring.

If you don't see the Immediate window, you can open it by selecting View --> Immediate Window from within the Visual Basic Editor.